# Relation between $\ell ^1$ and the $L^1$ space on the circle

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose  $\hat{f}(n)$ is the fourier coefficient of a function $f$ on the circle. I have seen in class that for $p=2,$ if $\{\hat{f}(n)\}_{n \mathbb{zZ}}$ is in $\ell^p$, then we have f is in the $L^p$ space.

I.e. if $\sum|\hat{f}(n)|^2< \infty,$ then f is in $L^2$.

Is it also true for p=1?

I.e. is it true that $\sum |\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$, then f is in $L^1?$

Comment: I suspect that $\hat f(n)$ is the Fourier coefficient/transform, so you might want to clarify what it is in this context.

Comment: @CheeHanC question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum |\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$, then the Fourier series converges uniformly. Therefore, its sum is a continuous function. A continuous function on a circle is integrable, so yes, the conclusion is true.

However, it's not as useful as the $p=2$ case because it cannot be inverted: there are plenty of $L^1$ functions whose Fourier coefficients are not in $\ell^1$ (for example, any bounded discontinuous function).